# Entity Framework code first optional ICollection relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I new to the code first Entity Framework and trying to solve a optional relationship.

I have the following models

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CardId { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    .......
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    .......

}
```

A customer may not have any cards so the relationship needs to be optional, a card must have a customer.

I have tried the following but the collection does not contain the definition for a customer.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    //.HasOptional(lu => lu.Cards)
    //.WithRequired(pi => pi.Customer);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Updated code to reflect suggestions below, unfortunately still no luck.

Comment: `ICollection<Card> Cards` should be defined as `virtual`

Comment: Yep tried that, added to the code example above. The problem is setting a 1-many-null relationship on the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it seems like you're trying to do is just create a One-to-Many relationship.

In your Cards model you need to include:

```
public int CustomerId { get; set; }  // Setting up a foreign key.
```

With this setup, the Customer class will not need:

```
public int? CardId { get; set; } // not necessary anymore
```

With a One-to-Many relationship, the `ICollection<Card> Cards` automatically allows 0 items to be allowed.  You do not by default have to build that collection.  Think of any collection.  You do not have to have any items added to that collection for it to exist.  You can also add many items, and take them away later and that's okay.

Comment: Thanks I have tried, some of the examples on here suggested removing the virtual but I have now put it back. I still get the error on the WithRequired I cant seem to map it to the customer?

Comment: I see you added in virtual. Did you also add in the foreign keys? CustomerId and CardId?  These are the int properties I recommended above.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion. Tried that and removing the code from the OnModelCreating however the relationship between Customer and Card is created as required and not optional.

Comment: Updated code above, maybe I am looking at this the wrong way and its not possible to create a many-0 relationship with a collection?

Comment: I see what you're doing now. Okay you do not need a CardId in your Customer model. By default, the Cards in your Customer class should be optional. You could have 0 or you could have 300 and it shouldn't matter. Are you encountering any errors or problems to make you think this isn't working?

Comment: Thanks Safari I got it working in the end, I have a further relationship in the card model, when I removed this it worked fine. Without your pointers I would not have thought it would be the issue.